# Quantifiers and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

Given the following statement,

$$\forall x \, (x \in S)$$

When we say "for every x in S", are we saying that every possible element is in S -- and there are no other elements, except x?

Comment: $x$ is a placeholder; when we say a first order formula $\forall x~(x\in S).\Phi(x)$ is true where $\Phi(x)$ is some first order formula in $x$, we mean that $\Phi(x)$ is true for every $x\in S$. If, say, $S=\{1,2,3\}$, then the mentioned formula amounts to saying that all of $\Phi(1),\Phi(2),\Phi(3)$ are true.

Comment: Compare with $\forall x (\text {Even(x)})$ that means "Every x is Even".

Comment: Is ∀x(Even(x)) True? or False?

Comment: No idea? what about $3$?

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is written more simply as
$$\forall x\in S$$
*On its own*, the expression is meaningless. It only has meaning when coupled with other statements. For example, consider the following:
$$|x|\geq x~~,\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$$
In words, this means "For **any** real number - $5$, $\log(\gamma)$, $\sqrt{\pi}$, etc,  its absolute value is greater than or equal to the number itself." The important point is the fact we used $x$ is irrelevant - the statement has exactly the same meaning if we write
$$|\text{banana}|\geq \text{banana}~~,\forall ~\text{banana}\in\Bbb{R}$$
In other words, the statement says nothing about "$x$" itself. $x$ is simply a placeholder that we use to represent "something contained in the set $S$".

Comment: Where did you import $|x\geq x, \; \forall x \in R$ from?  That is not part of the question.

Comment: @amWhy I was using it as an example.

Comment: Okay, I get why you'd want to do that, but please make it clear with more that E.g., Suppose we want to translate "for all real numbers $x, \, |x|\geq x$, and proceed as you do.  But I do like this answer, and will now upvote it.  I like the edit too!

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote amounts to

> Every  $x$ in our domain of discourse is an element of $S$

i.e., $S$ is a "set of everything".

Comment: So, basically yes then? Also, could you briefly explain what domain of discourse means?

Comment: @watchy It means whatever $\forall$ runs over.

Comment: Indeed, @J.G.  If $S$ is empty, and $x$ in the domain, say, of natural numbers, then $\forall x(x\in S)$ is false.  If you want to say something about every $x\in S$, perhaps that P(x), then you need to write $\forall x((x\in S) \to P(x)).$  But your question tells us nothing of the domain of the quantified $x$.  Of course, if you mean from the get go that every x in the set S is in the set S, then you should write $$\forall x(x\in S \to x\in S).$$  But note that this is true of for all $x \lnot in S$.

Comment: @watchy: I think it is taught as the "universal set" when you start learning about sets. Of course, most standard formal treatments of set theory (like $\mathsf{ZF}$) do not allow for the existence of a universal set because it is contradicted by the axiom of regularity+axiom of pairing (if you allow the notion of an universal set, you run into problems like Russell's paradox, etc)

Comment: Further to @PrasunBiswas's point, what we get in cases like $\mathsf{ZF}$ is a class of all sets, a proper class often called the universe.

Comment: I'd be okay if you wrote $\forall x \in \mathbb Z (x\in \mathbb R).$ Or equivalently, $\forall x(x\in \mathbb Z \to x\in \mathbb R)$.

Comment: I believe my confusion stemmed from not knowing what domain of discourse meant.